# Making a dynamic dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm attempting to make a dynamic dropdownlist, I have a list of meetings that each has a list of events that are attached to this meeting. At the moment I am following this example to make this work: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/cascading-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Now at step 4: there is this line of code:

```
$.each(data, function (i, district) {
  items += "<option value='" + district.Value + "'>" + district.Text + "</option>";
});
$('#District').html(items);
```

From what I understand I'm making a new list of districts here, but the "district" value here, is that a self-declared variable? So I could just leave it like that? (well of course it's not very clean but just for the sake of the question)

Also, in this line:

```
$.getJSON('/DDL/DistrictList/' + $('#State').val(), function (data)
```

DDL is the controllername, so if my controller were named ResultController, I'd have to type "Result" without the controller part here?

I'm sorry if this all seems trivial stuff, but I'm really new to MVC and jquery programming in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct the first part district is just a name for what the function is receiving so you can leave it as it is, or change it to something more suitable to you.

The second part is also correct. MVC knows that you are looking for a controller called Result so it doesnt need the controller part on the end. Quite clever really.

Comment: No problem, I am just over a year into learning both and still learn lots daily :)